# $f(x)$ be differentiable and have a local minimum in $x_0$, show with definition $f'_+(x_0)\ge0, f'_-(x_0)\le0, f'(x_0)=0$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

> Let $f(x)$ be differentiable in $x_0$, $x_0$ is a local minimum, prove with the definition that $f'_+(x_0)\ge0, f'_-(x_0)\le0, f'(x_0)=0$.

I get that $f$ is decreasing from the left and increasing from the right and the last part is true from squeeze theorem.

I need to show in some way that $f(x)$ is increasing in $x_0<x<x_0+\delta$ but I get stuck, we have

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0+}\frac{f(x_0+\delta)-f(x_0)}{x_0+\delta-x_0}$ and we know that $f(x)\ge f(x_0)$ but what about the numerator, how do we know that it's positive?

Comment: let the numerator be $f(x_0+\delta)-f(x_0)$ and $\delta>0$ and then compute for the right side limit.And the denominator changes to simply $\delta$. similarly for the left hand limit consider $f(x_0-\delta)-f(x_0)$ in the numerator and then the denominator becomes $-\delta$. hope this helped.

Comment: you must correct your limit it is not the tangent or the limit you are looking for at $x_0$

Comment: @Jasser if the denominator is $\delta$ how do we know that the numerator is positive?

Comment: As you said $f(x) \ge f(x_0)$ for all x in the given interval

Comment: @Jasser right, thanks for the help.

Comment: Enjoy learning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\delta>0$ be small enough to make it true that $$\frac{f\left(x_{0}+\epsilon\right)-f\left(x_{0}\right)}{\epsilon}\geq0\text{  and  }\frac{f\left(x_{0}-\epsilon\right)-f\left(x_{0}\right)}{-\epsilon}\leq0$$
for each $\epsilon\in\left(0,\delta\right)$.

This is possible because
$f$ has a local minimum at $x_{0}$ and results in $f'_{+}\left(x_{0}\right)\geq0$
and $f'_{-}\left(x_{0}\right)\leq0$ if we let $\epsilon$ approach
$0$.

From the fact that $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$ we are
allowed to conclude that $f'_{+}\left(x_{0}\right)=f'_{-}\left(x_{0}\right)$
and under the found conditions this can only be true if $f'_{+}\left(x_{0}\right)=0=f'_{-}\left(x_{0}\right)$
and also $f'\left(x_{0}\right)=0$.